# Two oracle db sets of data. How do I select data that is in one set and not in the other and vice versa

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have these two subqueries that I got working

```
(

SELECT GLOBAL_USERS.ID AS USER_ID, GLOBAL_USERS.USER_ID AS USERNAME,
    GLOBAL_USERS.DEPARTMENT AS DEPARTMENT,
    GLOBAL_USERS.FIRST_NAME AS FIRSTNAME, GLOBAL_USERS.LAST_NAME AS LASTNAME, 
    GLOBAL_USERS.TITLE AS TITLE,
    USER_FIRST_ENTITLEMENTS.ENTITLEMENT_NAME AS ENTITLEMENTNAME, 
    USER_FIRST_ENTITLEMENTS.APPLICATION_NAME AS APPLICATIONNAME 
FROM GLOBAL_USERS
INNER JOIN USER_FIRST_ENTITLEMENTS 
ON GLOBAL_USERS.ID=USER_FIRST_ENTITLEMENTS.USER_ID AND 
    (USER_FIRST_ENTITLEMENTS.APPLICATION_NAME='MY APPLICATION NAME'
    AND USER_FIRST_ENTITLEMENTS.ENTITLEMENT_NAME LIKE '%\fis\%')
) join1



(
SELECT DISTINCT injoin1.ID,injoin2.APPLICATION_ROLE_ID, injoin2.NAME FROM
(
    SELECT GLOBAL_USERS.ID,USER_SECOND_ENTITLEMENTS.APPLICATION_ROLE_ID 
    FROM GLOBAL_USERS
    INNER JOIN USER_SECOND_ENTITLEMENTS
    ON GLOBAL_USERS.ID=USER_SECOND_ENTITLEMENTS.USER_ID
    ) injoin1,
    (
    SELECT USER_SECOND_ENTITLEMENTS.APPLICATION_ROLE_ID,SECOND_ENTITLEMENT_DEFINITIONS.NAME 
    FROM USER_SECOND_ENTITLEMENTS
    INNER JOIN SECOND_ENTITLEMENT_DEFINITIONS
    ON USER_SECOND_ENTITLEMENTS.APPLICATION_ROLE_ID=SECOND_ENTITLEMENT_DEFINITIONS.ID
    ) injoin2
    WHERE injoin1.APPLICATION_ROLE_ID=injoin2.APPLICATION_ROLE_ID 
) join2
```

essentially, what I need to do now is see if every join1.ENTITLEMENTNAME for each join1.USER_ID exists for that same join2.ID in join2.NAME. If it doesn't exist then I need to have a row that says join1.USERNAME join1.DEPARTMENT, join1.FIRSTNAME, join1.LASTNAME, join1.TITLE, join1.ENTITLEMENTNAME, join1.APPLICATIONNAME

I, at the same time, need to see if every join2.NAME for each join2.ID exists for that same join1.USER_ID in join1.ENTITLEMENTNAME

I am a little lost on how to do this, but I am sure it is with some type of join.

Notes: comparing join1.ENTITLEMENTNAME's with join2.NAME's and the userids are in join1.USER_ID and join2.ID.

I'm not worried about efficiency or speed, I just need functionality, so a simple answer will suffice.

Extra brownie points if you help me with the regex. The join2.NAME's are stored as themselves, but the join1.ENTITLEMENTNAME's are stored as "/fis/" I'm not exactly sure how to filter on that so it would be helpful if anyone could explain.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Oracle's MINUS](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php) command?  It is like the inverse of a UNION.  It subtracts similarities between two queries so that the result set is the difference between the two.  It sounds like it's exactly what you need.  Just take your first set and MINUS the second set.

I *think* the below code is what you described, but you might need to modify it to fit your needs exactly.

```
SELECT 
    GLOBAL_USERS.ID AS USER_ID, 
    GLOBAL_USERS.USER_ID AS USERNAME,
    GLOBAL_USERS.DEPARTMENT AS DEPARTMENT,
    GLOBAL_USERS.FIRST_NAME AS FIRSTNAME, 
    GLOBAL_USERS.LAST_NAME AS LASTNAME, 
    GLOBAL_USERS.TITLE AS TITLE,
    USER_FIRST_ENTITLEMENTS.ENTITLEMENT_NAME AS ENTITLEMENTNAME, 
    USER_FIRST_ENTITLEMENTS.APPLICATION_NAME AS APPLICATIONNAME 
FROM GLOBAL_USERS
INNER JOIN USER_FIRST_ENTITLEMENTS 
    ON  GLOBAL_USERS.ID=USER_FIRST_ENTITLEMENTS.USER_ID 
    AND ( USER_FIRST_ENTITLEMENTS.APPLICATION_NAME='MY APPLICATION NAME'
          AND USER_FIRST_ENTITLEMENTS.ENTITLEMENT_NAME LIKE '%\fis\%')

MINUS

SELECT 
    GLOBAL_USERS.ID AS USER_ID, 
    GLOBAL_USERS.USER_ID AS USERNAME,
    GLOBAL_USERS.DEPARTMENT AS DEPARTMENT,
    GLOBAL_USERS.FIRST_NAME AS FIRSTNAME, 
    GLOBAL_USERS.LAST_NAME AS LASTNAME, 
    GLOBAL_USERS.TITLE AS TITLE,
    USER_SECOND_ENTITLEMENTS.ENTITLEMENT_NAME AS ENTITLEMENTNAME, 
    USER_SECOND_ENTITLEMENTS.APPLICATION_NAME AS APPLICATIONNAME 
FROM GLOBAL_USERS
INNER JOIN USER_SECOND_ENTITLEMENTS 
    ON  GLOBAL_USERS.ID=USER_SECOND_ENTITLEMENTS.USER_ID 
    AND ( USER_SECOND_ENTITLEMENTS.APPLICATION_NAME='MY APPLICATION NAME'
          AND USER_SECOND_ENTITLEMENTS.ENTITLEMENT_NAME LIKE '%\fis\%')
```

As far as the regex goes, `'%\/fis\/%'` should do the trick.  You needed to escape the `'/'`.

Comment: thank you for the tip. I'll do some research!
as far as the regex, I meant when i compare the two entitlements the comparison is like "blah/blah/blah/fis/entitl3"="entitl3"
I need to filter out on the comparison

Comment: You can put NOT in front of LIKE to exclude matches.